# Hadoop- How to run JobTracker?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I use *CDH5.4*, I want to start the JobTracker and TaskTracker with this command `sudo service hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker start` and `sudo service hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker start`, I got this error : **hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-jobtracker: Unrecognized service** same error with tasktraker why?

I tried to use the `start-all.sh` but I didn't find his location.. after that I used the `./mapred.sh` but It asks about password 
Please give me a solution to start the **jobtraker and tasktracker**

Comment: The form `service abc start` is the same as `/etc/init.d/abc start` -- confirm there is an executable script of the name specified in `/etc/init.d` -- it might just be `jobtracker`, for example

Comment: I dont fond any `abc start` in `/etc/init.d`, but I fond `hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver`. What I should do now to start jobtracker? Sir

Answer (score 0):

Please check HDFS service is installed or not and namenode and datanode an yarn

start-all.sh & stop-all.sh : Used to start and stop hadoop daemons all at once. Issuing it on the master machine will

start/stop the daemons on all the nodes of a cluster. Deprecated as you have already noticed.

start-dfs.sh, stop-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh, stop-yarn.sh : Same as above but start/stop HDFS and YARN daemons separately

on all the nodes from the master machine. It is advisable to use these commands now over start-all.sh & stop-all.sh

hadoop-daemon.sh namenode/datanode and yarn-deamon.sh resourcemanager : To start individual daemons on an individual

machine manually. You need to go to a particular node and issue these commands.

Comment: I use the `mapreduce v1 not yarn` Sir,  Namenode and Datanode start normaly I used `host:50070` it works but `host:50030` not work.
I use my personal computer only Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You're using CDH 5.4 so do not use the new very old version of MapReduce, use MR2 and YARN.  The jobTracker is a service that is part of YARN.  Use ClouderaManager to set up a single node by following their excellent instructions.

Comment: But Sir I should use the MR1 and the jobs